Optimizing MJPEG stream handling in Service Worker
Background:
I'm implementing a small react app in which an MJPEG stream transmitted by HTTPS is displayed. The stream is only accessible if the user is authorized (using Basic Auth). Therefore, I can not use a <img/>-tag for displaying the stream directly.
I found a working solution for that and tried to optimize the reading of the data and moving this logic to a Service Worker. During the optimization, I introduced some memory leaks. They are fixed now, but left me with the question, if my implementation of the worker and its communication with the main process is a good one (especially performance- and memory-wise).
Question:
Is the worker/main process communication implemented in a good way, and if not, what can be improved in order to make the stream fetching more performant?
The complete code is in the following repo: https://github.com/nimrod42/authorized_stream_viewer
The relevant parts are given below.
stream.js:
export class Stream {
  constructor(options) {
    this.url = options.url;
    this.token = options.token;
    this.render = options.render;
    this.controller = new AbortController();
    this.abortSignal = this.controller.signal;
  }

  close() {
    this.controller.abort();
  }

  //current
  async getFrame() {
    const response = await fetch(this.url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Authorization: this.token },
      cache: "no-cache",
      signal: this.abortSignal,
    });

    if (response.ok && response.body) {
      const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");

      if (contentType.startsWith("multipart/x-mixed-replace;")) {
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");

        let headers = "";
        let partType = "";
        let partLen = -1;
        let data = null;
        let readBytes = 0;
        let buffer = new Uint8Array(); // Buffer stores leftover data between reads

        while (true) {
          const { done, value } = await reader.read();
          if (done) break; // Finished with reading

          // Combine buffer data with new value
          const chunk = new Uint8Array(buffer.length + value.length);
          chunk.set(buffer);
          chunk.set(value, buffer.length);

          let offset = 0;

          while (offset < chunk.length) {
            // Read headers
            if (partLen === -1) {
              // Find JPEG start marker in the chunk
              for (let i = offset; i < chunk.length - 1; i++) {
                if (chunk[i] === 0xff && chunk[i + 1] === 0xd8) {
                  // Process headers
                  const headerString = decoder.decode(
                    chunk.subarray(offset, i),
                  );
                  headers += headerString; // Append any partial headers from previous reads

                  headers.split("\n").forEach((line) => {
                    const [key, val] = line
                      .split(":")
                      .map((s) => s.trim().toLowerCase());
                    if (key === "content-length") {
                      partLen = parseInt(val, 10);
                      data = new Uint8Array(partLen); // Allocate buffer for the image data
                    } else if (key === "content-type") {
                      partType = val;
                    }
                  });

                  offset = i; // Move offset to start of JPEG data
                  headers = ""; // Reset headers for next part
                  break;
                }
              }

              if (partLen === -1) {
                // No start marker found, keep accumulating headers
                headers += decoder.decode(chunk.subarray(offset));
                break;
              }
            }

            // Processing image data
            if (partLen > 0 && readBytes < partLen) {
              const bytesToRead = Math.min(
                partLen - readBytes,
                chunk.length - offset,
              );
              data.set(chunk.subarray(offset, offset + bytesToRead), readBytes);
              readBytes += bytesToRead;
              offset += bytesToRead;
            }

            // Process image by creating objectUrl and send it to main process
            if (readBytes === partLen) {
              let file = new Blob([data], { type: partType });
              if (file.type.startsWith("image")) {
                let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                this.render(objectUrl);
                setTimeout(() => {
                  URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
                  objectUrl = null;
                  file = null;
                }, 500);
              }
              // Reset for the next image
              readBytes = 0;
              partLen = -1;
              partType = "";
              data = null;
            }
          }

          // Save any remaining unprocessed data in the buffer
          if (offset < chunk.length) {
            buffer = chunk.subarray(offset);
          } else {
            buffer = new Uint8Array(); // Reset buffer if everything was processed
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


The app:
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { TOKEN } from "./CONSTANTS.js";

const imgId = "stream-image-id";

export const App = () => {
  // create worker which fetches streams and returns objectUrls for displaying
  // in image tag
  useEffect(() => {
    const img = document.getElementById(imgId);
    const worker = new Worker(
      new URL("/public/stream-worker.js", import.meta.url),
    );
    worker.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
      img.onload = () => URL.revokeObjectURL(message.data);
      img.src = message.data;
    });
    worker.postMessage({ command: "start", token: TOKEN });

    return () => {
      if (worker) {
        worker.postMessage({ command: "close" });
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Authorized Stream Viewer</h1>
      <img id={imgId} alt={"stream-viewer"} />
    </>
  );
};

And the Service Worker:
import { Stream } from "/src/stream.js";
import { STREAM_URL } from "../src/CONSTANTS.js";

let stream;

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  const { token, command } = event.data;

  if (command === "start") {
    stream = new Stream({
      render: (img) => self.postMessage(img),
      url: STREAM_URL,
      token,
    });
    stream.getFrame();
  } else {
    if (stream) {
      stream.close();
    }
  }
});

